# How do I Save/Pin a New Window, and assign a button to it?

Tags: python, windows, workspaces

Under Window > New Window,
I'm able to create a window, and assign various Editor Types within said window. I'd like to save this window and Pin it, so that regardless of which Workspace Tab I'm on it stays the same, and regardless if it's closed I'll be able to re-open it and all of my situated Editor Types are retained. Ideally I would like to assign this window to a button in a display panel that I'm creating (I already know how to make a display panel and buttons, just not how to assign a window to one in this particular case).

[image]

Saving as a new Startup file doesn't exactly work, because I'd like to have this window available regardless of what file I'm opening.

Comment: I like this idea! Wish I knew how to do this. Hopefully someone will answer.